# How can set up a Google Sheet menu via AppsScript to pull all of my emails from gmail?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Hi I am trying to create a menu on a Google Sheet that lets me pull all of my emails from Gmail. I can't figure out how to do this with the new Google Apps Script vs. the old menu of Tools <- Script Editor that would let you run. I'm not sure if its because I'm deploying to Web App or if I should be deploying as an Add On. I am deploying with changes and the menu item I got to create on first try isn't showing as well.

I am using Tiago's code from Github but this is written with the old Tools Script menu and I can't figure out how to use Apps Script.
https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/gmail-to-google-sheets-script/blob/master/gmailt-to-sheets.gs

```
  /** 
 * Creates the menu item "Mail Merge" for user to run scripts on drop-down.
 */
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Get Gmail Emails')
      .addItem('Get Email', 'saveEmails')
      .addToUi();
}

// This Google Script searchs on your Gmail account, and store the results on a Google Sheet file
// Original: https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/gmail-to-google-sheets-script/

// Add here your search query. Do your search on gmail first, copy and paste the search terms here
// Samples: "label: hiring-process", "to: sales@mycompany.com"
var SEARCH_QUERY = '';
// If you want each email address just once on sheet, set to true
var AVOID_REPEATED_ADDRESS = false;

// Main function, the one that you must select before run
function saveEmails() {
    console.log("Clearing sheet...");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear();  
  
    console.log(`Searching for: "${SEARCH_QUERY}"`);
    var start = 0;
    var max = 500;
    
    var threads = GmailApp.search(SEARCH_QUERY, start, max);
    if (threads!=null){
      console.log("Threads found ");
      console.log("Paginating to collect email addresses...");
    } else {
      console.warn("No emails found within search criteria ");
      return;
    }

    // Add Sheet header collumns ✏️
    appendData(1, [["Date","From Address", "to Address"]]);
    
    var totalEmails = 0;
    var emails = [];
    var addresses = [];
    while (threads.length>0){
      for (var i in threads) {
          var thread=threads[i];
          var data = thread.getLastMessageDate();
          var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
          for (var j in msgs) {
            var msg = msgs[j];

            // Values to get and store ✏️
            var data = msg.getDate();          
            var from = msg.getFrom();
            var to = msg.getTo();
            // var subject = msg.getSubject();
            var dataLine = [data,from,to];

            // Add values to array
            if (!AVOID_REPEATED_ADDRESS || (AVOID_REPEATED_ADDRESS && !addresses.includes(to))){
              emails.push(dataLine);
              addresses.push(to);
            }
          }
      }

      totalEmails = totalEmails + emails.length;

      // Add emails to sheed
      appendData(2, emails);

      if (threads.length == max){
          console.log("Reading next page...");
      } else {
          console.log("Last page readed ");
      }
      start = start + max; 
      threads = GmailApp.search(SEARCH_QUERY, start, max);
    }

    console.info(totalEmails+" emails added to sheet ");
}

// Add contents to sheet
function appendData(line, array2d) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(line, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. With respect, your question is pretty vague and doesn't explain the EXACT problem that you are having. You need to supply more information so that we can try and solve a specific problem. FYI: there is NO difference between the results generated by the "Old" vs "New" editor. _I'm not sure if its because I'm deploying to Web App or if I should be deploying as an Add On_ I respectfully suggest that you ignore this aspect, and ignore `onOpen` too. Concentrate on `saveEmails()` - does it work or not? If not, then what is the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pull all the e-mails and paste them in your active sheet, you can paste the following code in Extensions-App Script:

```
function getContacts() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts()
  var listContacts = []
  
  for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    var name = contacts[i].getFullName() //I'm extracting name and addresss. You can add more values
    var address = contacts[i].getEmailAddresses()[0] //Here I'm just logging the first of the e-mail addresses in order to keep a 2 column table
    listContacts.push([name,address])
  }
  //Logger.log(listContacts)
  listContacts = listContacts.sort((a, b) => { //this sorts alphabetically by name, in case you need
      var xp = a[0];
      var yp = b[0];
      return xp == "" ? 2: yp == "" ? -2: xp == yp ? 0 :  xp < yp ? -1 : 1; //the first two conditions leave the empty cells at the bottom
    });

  sheet.getRange(1,1,listContacts.length,2).setValues(listContacts) //I'm starting at 1,1 (which means A1 of the active sheet), you can change it to another value; or make it start at the active range from which you're selecting the menu
}

function onOpen(){ //here is the personalized menu
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Contacts") 
    .addItem("Get Contacts","getContacts")
    .addToUi()
}
```

Is this helpful??

PS: remember to run it once from the App Script menu to allow permissions

Comment: Hi. What am I missing here? The OP wants to list all **emails**. Your code lists all **contacts**. Notwithstanding this, the OP includes some code though they don't explain the problem with that code.

Comment: My bad... Mistranslation at it best/worst